# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado: 'billing.csv'

Tags: python, base-de-datos, postgresql, pandas

buenas tardes. Necesito ayuda con lo que estoy haciendo. Estoy intentando armar un dataframe con datos extraidos de una base postgre para poder ingestarlos en una base vertica. Para ello utilizo algunas funciones de verticaPY, y hasta el momento todo me andaba perfecto y pude insetar un registro. Pero ahora me tira este error y he buscado en todas partes pero no entiendo bien la verdad cómo resolver esto. Si me pueden ayudar, les agradecería desde ya.
Mi código logra ejecturase correctamente hasta el print(frame_ARG) con el frame que corresponde y es de mi interés. El error creo que surge al pasar a la siguiente línea, la de insercción...

```
ultimo_id_AR = vp.readSQL("select NVL(max(billing_id),0) LAST_BILLING_ID from POCDATA.billing where SERVER='AR'")
query = f"SELECT 'AR' as SERVER, * FROM hca.billing WHERE billing_id BETWEEN {ultimo_id_AR['LAST_BILLING_ID'][0]} AND {ultimo_id_AR['LAST_BILLING_ID'][0]} + 1"
frame_ARG = pd.read_sql(query,connection_db_postgre_AR())
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
print(frame_ARG)
vp.pandas_to_vertica(df = frame_ARG, name = "billing", schema = "POCDATA", insert = True)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto una imágen de el proceso cómo se ve el código y la salida en general

Comment: tiene una  tabla llamada pocdata.billing?

Comment: Seguramente no pueda crear el fichero csv intermedio por problemas de permisos. Intenta usar el argumento `temp_path`.

Comment: @Bryro Si, asi es tengo una tabla creada billing y el esquema es POCDATA.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Si, probe usar ese parámetro de VertticaPY, y le pasé la ruta actual de la carpeta dónde estoy trabajando y tengo todos los archivos pero no funcionó tampoco...